# Will clearing my app from recent tasks stop receiving broadcasts?

Tags: android, service, background, broadcastreceiver

I have created a service class in order to receive broadcasts in background. But as soon as I clear it from recent task it stops receiving broadcasts. Is it impossible to receive broadcasts after clearing the recent task or there is a way ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your actions registered in Manifest, your app will be triggered by system or other apps (exported broadcast set to true).

Specify the `<receiver>` element in your app's manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="your.package.action.CUSTOM_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When other app broadcast with action `your.package.action.CUSTOM_ACTION` will trigger your broadcast.

**Note: From Android 8.0, custom actions will not trigger event registered from Manifest. If you need to use custom actions, you can create service always run in background, then register broadcast inside. For example:**

```
class MyBackgroundService: Service() {
   override fun onStart() {
      super.onStart()
      val actionsFilter = IntentFilter()
      actionsFilter.addAction("your.package.actions.CUSTOM_ACTION")
      this.applicationContext.registerReceiver(myCustomReceiver, actionsFilter)
   }

   override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int) {
      return START_STICKY
   }

   override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent) {
      // your service has stopped, restart your service here...
      super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
   }


   private val myCustomReceiver = object: BroadcastReceiver() {
      // ...
   }
}
```

Don't forget to register your service from Manifest:

```
<service
   android:name=".MyBackgroundService"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:exported="true" />
```

From Android N, background service need to register foreground notification, so you need to display foreground notification when service created:

```
override fun onCreate() {
   super.onCreate()
   // register foreground service
   this.startForeground(notificationServiceId, yourNotificationInstance)
}
```